# Is it possible to execute scripts upon received emails?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I want to process an email programmatically, immediately when it's received. Is there something that allows me to do this conveniently (e.g. a hook in the Mail app, or somehow with Automator)?

Comment: Did you check out Mail rules within Mail Preferences?

Comment: A mail rule can run an applescript.

Comment: Nice! The AppleScript rule seems to provide the content of the message and it also seems to be possible to execute other programs, so I don't have to write everything in AppleScript. Thanks.